# Where does the Zagreb airport bus leave from at the bus station?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, croatia, zagreb, zag

The [WikiVoyage page on Zagreb](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Zagreb#By_plane) has this to say on the bus which runs between Zagreb airport and the city centre:

> The bus line between the bus station and the airport is slightly more complicated. Full details are available in English from <link which 404s>

While this does provide an excellent reason why we should include the helpful parts of external articles in our answers, to avoid the problem when the remote site changes/goes, it does leave me unable to find out what the trick is...

Does anyone know what is complicated about finding/getting the airport bus from the Zagreb bus station (Autobusni kolodvor) and the Airport, and where I should be going to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a lot simpler than the WikiVoyage article makes out, so no need
to worry! (I've now fixed that page...). The bus company website has changed recently, and the new timetable page is now http://www.plesoprijevoz.hr/zagrebzracna.html

If coming on foot from the city centre, your best be is to walk along Ul. kneza Branimira past the Graffiti wall, then turn onto Avenija Marina Drzica. You'll see the bus station on your right, and the Airport bus goes from the first building you come to in the bus station, which is white and labelled with
Croatian Airlines and Eurolines. Walk through the ticket office and out to
where the bus goes from. Pay the driver on boarding.

If coming by tram, take a 2, 5, 6, 7 or 8 to Autobusni Kolodvor (the bus station). Cross over to the bus station side, and turn right. Walk north
(towards the railway line) to the end of the bus station, with the shops on your
left. The very end part of the building is labelled with Croatian Airlines and
Eurolines, and that's the part you want.

If you need to change trams to get there, be aware that the stops at Drziceva are all a long way apart, so it's not a good place to change. Either get off there and walk (it's only a couple of minutes), or change at Olipska where the platforms are opposite.

The airport buses don't leave from the main part of the bus station, so if you're in there you'll need to exit down to the street, walk to the end of the building and enter the dedicated airport buses part there. It currently costs kn 30 one way, payable to the driver in cash on boarding. There are cash machines outside a few of the shops on the main road outside if you need them, and coming from the airport there's a cash machine inside baggage reclaim, and others in the main airport building.

Answer (score 4):

The Internet Archive to the rescue! (*)

[The last good scrape of the 404-ing resource you mention](http://web.archive.org/web/20120301000000%2a/http://www.plesoprijevoz.hr/schedulezg.htm), captured on October 1 2012, looks like this:

> ### ZAGREB (TERMINAL - MAIN BUS STATION) => ZAGREB AIRPORT
>
> Every day from Terminal (Main bus station): MON-SUN
>
> ```
> 4:30* 5:00 5:30 6:00 6:30 7:00 7:30 8:00 8:30 9:00 10:00
> 10:30 11:00 11:30 12:00 12:30 13:00 13:30 14:00 14:30 15:00
> 15:30 16:00 16:30 17:00 17:30 18:00 18:30 19:00 19:30 20:00 and 20:30
> ```
>
> * On Monday, Thuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and
>   Sunday the first bus from the terminal leaves at 04:30
>
> ** On monday and sunday the last bus from terminal leaves at 21:00
>
> *** On firday the last bus from terminal leaves at 21:00
>
> For early and late departures please email or phone to check.

so I think the wikivoyage page simply means to say "[**the timetable**] is slightly more complicated". That page does however have this info about *where* to catch the bus:

> The buses are located at the edge (facing city center) of the bus
>   station. You'll see "Croatia Airlines" and "Eurolines" written on that
>   part of the building.

---

<sup>(*) With a dead url like this `http://blah`, just navigate to `http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://blah` and you will be able to see if and when the Archive scraped it</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The link works for me.  It doesn't look complicated, just that the route goes around a few places in town.  Here's the map:

[image]

There's also a timetable, and the following paragraph:

> For departures before 6:00 AM and after 22:00 PM, plese call: +385 01
>   6331-982 or by email: plesoprijevoz@plesoprijevoz.hr After the 8 pm
>   (20:00) buses from Zagreb Airport leave shortly after the arrival of
>   the aircrafts.
>
> price for one way ticket 30,00 Kn
>
> price for allday ticket two way 40,00 Kn